# Using VBA to set Conditional Formatting and Highlighting

Tags: vba, formatting, conditional-statements

Is there a way to use VBA to set conditional formatting to highlight the row or the cell on an excel spreadsheet if column K is less than column L?

I have had a route around the first few google pages that come up when searching but I can't get anything to work :(

```
Sub SpecCheck()
Dim iRow As Range, cell as Range ' I also added the cell as Range
Set iRow = Range("$J$2:$L$50")

For Each cell In iRow
    If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > Range("$L$2").Value And cell.Value < Range("$K$2").Value Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The answer is yes. Can you share your attempts, even if not working as you expected?

Comment: @FaneDuru I have added in my latest attempt, thanks for your time

Comment: What you ask is not reflected in the code you posted... So, do you need some conditional formatting to be applied on a slice of "K:K" column against "L:L" column. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes so if the value of L is less than the value of K I would like it to highlight either the row or highlight just the cell in question

Comment: If so, did you check my answer code? It highlights the cell (if it is not empty)...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you! that worked, it highlights the cell in column K when there is a difference, would you know how I can get it to highlight J,K & L if there was a difference instead of just column K? I have tried changing to  Set rng = Range("J2:L10") but this just highlights everything but that row, I will mark your answer with a tick, thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Yes, it can be done. All the range will be defined, but formula will use absolute reference for columns. I will edit the answer and add another piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub SpecFormatConditions()
 Dim rng As Range, condition1 As FormatCondition

 Set rng = Range("K2:K10")
  
  With rng
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    Set condition1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And(" & _
             .cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "<>"""", " & .cells(1).Address(0, 0) & ">" & _
             .cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")")
  End With
   With condition1
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End With
End Sub
```

To modify the interior for a larger range (in terms of columns), formulas containing absolute reference for columns must be used:

```
Sub SpecFormatConditionsThreColumns()
 Dim rng As Range, condition1 As FormatCondition

 Set rng = Range("J2:L10")
  
  With rng
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    Set condition1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And($K2 <>"""", $K2 < $L2)")
  End With
   With condition1
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Again thank you for your time you are very kind!, unfortunately this doesn't highlight anything though :(

Comment: @PaulDN: This is not possible, or I did not understand what is to be done. The above code (tested) should highlight the range J:L in case of a value in K is less then the L value **on the same row**. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @PaulDN:   I did not modify anything... If you found a proper way of testing, this is OK.